# PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController not calling delegate

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I've set up a PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController with a valid PKPaymentRequest, logged in an account from the Sandbox with a valid test card and [shipping address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228985/pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontroller-not-nil-but-not-showing). I've changed the region to USA, but nothing changed. The app has all the valid certificates and entitilements.

```
func getApplePayController(request: PKPaymentRequest) -> PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController? {
            guard let vc = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request) else {
                return nil
            }

            //Set ourselves as delegate to get callbacks on the transaction status
            vc.delegate = self

            //we keep a weak reference to the controller to be able to dismiss it if necessary
            self.applePayViewController = vc//This is weak

            return vc
        }
```

And to present:

```
//Show Apple Pay screen with configured PKPaymentRequest object
        guard let vc = getApplePayController(request: paymentRequest) else {
            dLog("Error instantiating Apple Pay screen")
            handleEventType(.status(.failed))
            return
        }

        assert(delegate != nil)
        assert(applePay.didAuthorize == false)
        assert(vc.delegate != nil)

        //disable swipe to dismiss
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            vc.isModalInPresentation = true
        }

        if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }

            // topController should now be your topmost view controller
            topController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

The screen shows up, if I click on cancel everything freezes. If I click on the background the screen gets automatically dismissed, but the rest of the view is not interactive (PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController is not dismissed, but its ui is hidden). If I click on Pay it asks for the pin and it's stuck processing. No delegate is called in either case.

My implementation:

```
public func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
print("Dismiss")
}

public func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController,
                                 didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment,
                                                  completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {
           completion(.success)
           return;
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
        public func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController,
                                 didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment,
                                                     handler: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
            handler(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult(status: .success, errors: nil))
           return;
}
```

Not one of the three methods is ever called, no matter what I do. I've checked and the delegate is set up correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: show how you present and assign the delegates for  `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController `

Comment: I have this issue also, but only on simulator, assumed it was a bug and moved on, interesting to see if there is a fix.

Comment: Updated the question. Happens on both device and simulator

Comment: @vale did you figure it out? also experiencing same

Comment: Yes, I answered my own question with what worked for me, but given the downvotes it does not work for most people...

Answer (score -2):

I now implemented also PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate even though I' not using it and it works...

```
    public func paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
    return
}
```